# How to remove all items that matches index in myindexes array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a itemArray, and I need remove all item index that contained in another array indexArray.

```swift
list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
rows = [2, 4]

for i in rows {
   list.remove(at: i)
}
```

I do want to remove "3", "5", but the above code will be crash. I need set rows = [4, 2], remove to worked well

Comment: Share some code. What have you tried?

Comment: This came up recently on the Swift forums: https://forums.swift.org/t/implementing-a-collection-removingindicies/27681?u=alexanderm

Comment: @Alexander thank you for telling, this is really a good thing.

Comment: you can refer this too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872151/7301439

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing because after you're delete the element at *index-2*, the elements `count` in `array` is reduced. Hence, when deleting element at *index-5*, it results in runtime exception `"Index out of bounds"`.

So, you need to `sort` the `rows` `array` in *decreasing order* and then delete the elements from `list` one by one, i.e.

```
var list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var rows = [2, 4]
rows.sorted(by: >).forEach({ list.remove(at: $0) })
print(list) //["1", "2", "4"]
```

Comment: You can simplify it with `sorted(by: >)`

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: Yep, looks good. I would also omit the https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=parentheses&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 and use trailing closure syntax: `.forEach { list.remove(at: $0) }`. Optionally, you could use partial method application instead: `.forEach(list.remove(at:))`