# CollectionView crashing after I try deleting multiple (programmatically added) cells

Tags: swift, crash, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with a very simple data source. It's just an array of strings that gets updated programmatically. With this UICollectionView, I can tap to select multiple cells - then can use a Delete button to remove all of the selected cells. Quite simple, except I SOMETIMES get a fatal error: Index out of range.

The cells get programmatically added by tapping cells in another collection view called "All Hobbies" - Whatever cells get tapped & selected in the "All Hobbies" CV get added into "My Hobbies." I do this by appending the value of the tapped cell to the array controlling the My Hobbies CV.

**The problem**

1. Depending on what cells I select in My Hobbies, the delete button (code below) sometimes deletes them, or it sometimes crashes with fatal error: Index out of range. It does not seem to crash on first delete (if that helps.)
2. If the cells in My Hobbies actually DO delete, when I tap more cells in "All Hobbies" - they add to "My Hobbies" as UIColor.red (which denotes they are selected.) (and then will late crash after I press the delete btn.) Cells should be added as Yellow.

It seems like my data is not being updated after delete, and when I try deleting again, the index is out of range. However I can't find the issue in my code that is making that happening (if that really IS the issue...)

**Class Level**

```
let allHobbiesArray = ["Skiing", "Jogging", "Bicycling", "Basketball", "Cricket", "Being a Couch Potato", "Skiing", "Jogging", "Bicycling", "Basketball", "Cricket", "Being a Couch Potato", "Skiing", "Jogging", "Bicycling", "Basketball", "Cricket", "Being a Couch Potato", "Skiing", "Jogging", "Bicycling", "Basketball", "Cricket", "Being a Couch Potato"]
var myHobbiesArray = [String]()
var allSelected = [IndexPath]()
```

**Data Source**

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ALL", for: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
        cell.allHobbiesLabel.text = allHobbiesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MY", for: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.myHobbiesLabel.text = myHobbiesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        return allHobbiesArray.count
    }
    else {
        return myHobbiesArray.count
    }
}
```

**Delegate**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        let cell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell

        myHobbiesArray.append(allHobbiesArray[indexPath.row])

        myHobbiesCV.reloadData()
        for i in 0..<allSelected.count {
            self.myHobbiesCV.selectItem(at: allSelected[i], animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
        }
    }

    else {
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // Red background to show that it's selected

        // Store all of the selected cells in allSelected
        allSelected = self.myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!

    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == allHobbiesCV {
        let cell = allHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AllHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
    else {
        let cell = myHobbiesCV.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyHobbiesCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // update allSelected after deselect
        allSelected = self.myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems!

    }

}
```

**Deleting the cells**

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if allSelected.count > 0 {
        for element in allSelected {
            removeSelectedCells(i: element.item)
        }
    }
}

func removeSelectedCells(i: Int) {
    self.myHobbiesArray.remove(at: i) // This is what Xcode shows as the crash on the fatal error.
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: i, section: 0)

    self.myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: NSArray(object: indexPath) as! [IndexPath])

    //self.myHobbiesCV.performBatchUpdates({
    //    self.myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: NSArray(object: indexPath) as! [IndexPath])
    //}) { (true) in
    //    self.myHobbiesCV.reloadData()
    //}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated to handle the deleting of multiple cells from a Collection View. If you need more information I will be happy to clarify.

Comment: I think you have a couple of issues. You are calling `reloadData()` each time you make a deletion. Since you are calling `performBatchUpdates` you should not have to reload the collectionView. Also the `performBatchUpdates` method is meant to perform multiple updates (insert, deletes, edits) at a time. Since you are only deleting, a single `deleteItems(at: )` call should be enough.

Comment: @dkw5877 - I've made that adjustment in code and in this post. Didn't seem to fix my issues though. Still getting the crash randomly.

Comment: You only want to call `performBatchUpdates` once, not as part of a loop. Try moving this into 'deleteButtonPressed' as the last line. Basically there are two steps, remove the items from the data source (`myHobbiesArray`) and then call `deleteItems(at: )`

Comment: You should be able to use the `allSelected` array as input into `performBatchUpdates `, something like `self.myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: allSelected)`

Comment: @dkw5877 here's my delete button now:             for i in 0..<allSelected.count {
                self.myHobbiesArray.remove(at: i)
            }
            self.myHobbiesCV.performBatchUpdates({
                self.myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: self.allSelected)
            }) { (true) in
                // completion
            }  -- but unfortunately I am still getting a "fatal error: Index out of range" crash.

Comment: One more thought is that you are mutating the `myHobbiesArray` array using the indexPath.item value to determine the array item to remove. However, with each removal the selected hobby's index is being changed so that your indexPath.item no longer ties to the correct index. Try storing the hobby strings in an array, then you can filter the array `let myHobbiesArray = myHobbiesArray.filter { !selectedHobbies.contains($0) }`

Comment: See my previous comment. Lets say you have a selected indexPath.item array of `[2, 3]` and initallialy you have hobbies indices of `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.You want to remove items 2 & 3 from the hobbie array. After the first pass you have hobbies indices of `[0, 1, 2]`, you then try to remove indexPath.item = 3, but that index no longer exists so you crash.

Comment: @dkw5877 Thank you for your help here! Your explanation in your last comment makes sense as to why it's crashing. Not too sure where your code suggestion should go in the scope of the VC though.. is selectedHobbies a new Array you want me to create? Or can I use myHobbiesArray?

Comment: `selectedHobbies` would be a new array to track the hobbies that are going to be deleted, similar to how you are tracking the indexPath of the cells. You would update this in the `didSelectItemAt` and `didDeselectItemAt`. Check this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909855/remove-multiple-indices-from-array-in-swift). You might be able to remove multiple indexs at one time.

Comment: @dkw5877 - i'm having a tough time comprehending this selectedHobbies array. I added it in my project, but it's the same exact Array as allHobbiesArray. What's the point? You mind posting an answer with a rough solution that I can work off of? Something's not clicking, lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138069/discussion-between-dkw5877-and-joe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909855/remove-multiple-indices-from-array-in-swift), you should be able to get the indices from the `allSelected` array of indexPaths, and then remove the indices from the `myHobbiesArray`all at once.

```
@IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indices = allSelected.map{ $0.item } 
    myHobbiesArray = myHobbiesArray.enumerated().flatMap { indices.contains($0.0) ? nil : $0.1 }
    self.myHobbiesCV.deleteItems(at: allSelected)
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. That does the job perfectly. I just need to brush up on the map / flatMap methods. If you wouldn't mind, can you go over what the second line is doing? "myHobbiesArray = myHobbiesArray.enumerated().flatMap { indices.contains($0.0) ? nil : $0.1 }" you rock!

Comment: See the link the other SO answer, where the author explains the line in question in detail. He also provides an alternative implementation.